# How to squeeze the logistic function obliquely?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, transformation, continuous-variables

The original function: $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-10(x-0.5)}} $. Its graph (blue line) is shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rn2Ho.jpg):

[image: Graph]

How can I squeeze this function obliquely along the $y=x$ line? The squeezed function $g$ needs to satisfy that $g(0.5) = 0.5$, $g(0)$ is close to $0$, and $g(1)$ is close to $1$. The graph of this function $g$ that I have in mind is the black line in the image above.

Comment: You might call your function $g$ instead of $f'$ to avoid confusion with the derivative of $f$.

Comment: Good idea. Fixed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options here.  You could simply take $g(x) = t x + (1-t) f(x)$ for $0 < t < 1$, but presumably you want $0 < g(x) < 1$ for all $x$.  You could somehow define $g(x)$ piecewise, but this would not be smooth.

If you want a smooth function $g(x)$ with $0 < g(x) < 1$, $g(x) \approx 0$ for $x < 0$, $g(x) \approx 1$ for $x > 1$, and $g(x) \approx x$ for $0 < x  < 1$, you can use $g_a(x) = L_a(x) - L_a(1-x) + 1-x$ where $L_a(x) = \frac{1}{a}\log(1 + \exp(ax))$ is the [softplus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)#Softplus) and $a$ is a parameter that makes $g(x)$ closer to $x$ between $0$ and $1$.

[image]

If you want a function that looks closer to $f(x)$, you could try something like $y = tg_a(x) + (1-t) f(x)$, shown here for $a = 30$ and various $t$.

[image]

Comment: I didn't specify it in my question, but I want $g(x)$ to be greater than $y=x$ on (most of) the $(0.5,1.0)$ interval and less than $y=x$ on $(0.0,0.5)$, so your second solution suits my needs better.

Comment: I guessed as much, which is why I put it there :)  

Note that softplus can have numerical issues for large $x$ or $a$, since it is computing an exponential. You could replace it with the [squareplus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)#Squareplus) which has a similar shape but no numerical problems.

Comment: By numerical, do you mean computationally?

Comment: Yes, computationally.